# Running Docker image of Postman from Gitlab CI pipeline

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, postman-collection-runner

I want to run a [Postman](https://www.postman.com/product/rest-client/) collection from a Docker image in a Gitlab CI pipeline.  The Docker socket file is already mounted for the gitlab-ci-runner so the runner has access to the docker server.

Here's the job definition from .gitlab-ci.yaml

```
postman:
    image: docker:20.10.14
    stage: schedule
    only: 
        - schedules
    before_script: []
    script:
        - env
        - docker run -t -v $CI_PROJECT_DIR:/etc/newman postman/newman run postman_collection.json
```

The console output of the gitlab CI runner looks like this:

```
    $ docker run -t -v $CI_PROJECT_DIR:/etc/newman postman/newman run postman_collection.json
error: collection could not be loaded
  unable to read data from file "postman_collection.json"
  ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'postman_collection.json'
```

The file exists. I even tried

```
 docker run --rm -it -v $PWD:/etc/newman --entrypoint sh postman/newman
```

from my localhost console and ran it manually. It's all there.  What am I missing?

- List item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Docker socket file is already mounted for the gitlab-ci-runner

The problem here is that in the scenario where you are talking to the host docker daemon (i.e., when the host docker socket in mounted in the job), when you pass the volume argument to `docker run` like `-v /source/path:/container/path` the `/source/path` part of the argument refers to **the host filesystem** not the filesystem of the job container.

Think about it like this: the host docker daemon doesn't know that its socket is mounted inside the job container. So when you run `docker` commands this way, it's as if you're running the `docker` command on the runner host!

Because `$PWD` and `$CI_PROJECT_DIR` in your job command evaluates to a path in the **job container** (and this path isn't on the runner host filesystem) the volume mount will not work as expected.

This limitation is noted in the [limitations of Docker socket binding](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#limitations-of-docker-socket-binding) documentation:

> Sharing files and directories from the source repository into containers may not work as expected. Volume mounting is done in the context of the host machine, not the build container

---

The easiest workaround here would likely be to use `postman/newman` as your `image:` instead of `docker`.

```yaml
myjob:
  image: 
    name: postman/newman
    entrypoint: [""]

  script:
    - newman run postman_collection.json
```

Comment: That was extremely helpful! Thank you. Please indulge one more question for my understanding: Why do I need to override the entrypoint and then add "newman ..." to the script? The entrypoint in the image is already "newman". Why won't the script "run ..." work?

Comment: @LawrenceI.Siden glad this was helpful for you. Regarding the `entrypoint`, basically this is required because of how GitLab passes job scripts to the job container (and therefore how images are expected to receive and execute scripts -- specifically, images are expected to read scripts from `stdin` and do not get arguments to the entrypoint). This is partly explained [in the docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#override-the-entrypoint-of-an-image).